# Spring yaml environment not working together with datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an application.yml that works and is being used when connecting to the database:

```
spring:
 datasource:
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://10.100.247.112:5432/ofbizBuchhandel
  username: buchhandel
  password: buchhandel
```

When I add an environment profile to the configuration:

```
spring:
 profiles: development
 datasource:
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://10.100.247.112:5432/ofbizBuchhandel
  username: buchhandel
  password: buchhandel
```

I'm getting this **error**:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'demoApplication':  Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Could not
>   autowire field: com.example.DbAccess com.example.DemoApplication.dbd; 
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error
>   creating bean with name 'dbAccess':  Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Could not
>   autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
>   com.example.DbAccess.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Could not
>   autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]:  Factory method 'dataSource' threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Cannot
>   determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If
>   you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the
>   classpath.

From my understanding here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment the setting for profiles looks correct.

Comment: Did you specify the active profile while running? since you dont have default profile.

Comment: I specified the profile, but there was a typo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is that I just made a typo :(